# How to add 1 records data to previous?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

i am stuck in problem like i am passing accountID and on the basis of that SP picks amount details of a person e.g.

```
AccountID   AccountTitle  TransactionDate Amount

1           John01        2014/11/28      20
```

now if there is 2nd or more records for same accountID then it should add with previous e.g. if 2nd record for accountID 1 is 40 then amount should display 60 (such that it should be already added to 20 and display total in 2nd record)

```
AccountID   AccountTitle  TransactionDate Amount

    1           John01        2014/12/30    60    (in real it was 40 but it should show result after being added to 1st record)
```

and same goes for further records

```
Select Payments.Accounts.AccountID, Payments.Accounts.AccountTitle, 
       Payments.Transactions.DateTime as TranasactionDateTime, 
       Payments.Transactions.Amount from Payments.Accounts
       Inner Join Payments.Accounts
       ON Payments.Accounts.AccountID = Payments.Transactions.Account_ID
       Inner Join Payments.Transactions
       where Payments.Transactions.Account_ID = 1
```

it has wasted my time and can't tackle it anymore, so please help me,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server 2012+ supports cumulative sums (which seems to be what you want):

```
Select a.AccountID, a.AccountTitle, t.DateTime as TranasactionDateTime, 
       t.Amount,
       sum(t.Amount) over (partition by t.Account_Id order by t.DateTime) as RunningAmount    
from Payments.Accounts a Inner Join
     Payments.Transactions t
     on a.AccountID = t.Account_ID
where t.Account_ID = 1;
```

In earlier versions of SQL Server you can most easily do this with a correlated subquery or using `cross apply`.

I also fixed your query.  I don't know why you were joining to the Accounts table twice.  Also, table aliases make queries much easier to write and to read.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer if grouping by all columns is acceptable to you.

```
Select AccountID, AccountTitle, TransactionDate, SUM(Payments.Transactions.Amount)
from Payments.Accounts
group by AccountID, AccountTitle, TransactionDate
```

If you want to group only by AccountId, The query is this:

```
Select AccountID, SUM(Payments.Transactions.Amount)
from Payments.Accounts
group by AccountID
```

In the second query, the AccountTitle and TransactionDate are missing because they are not used in the group by clause. To include them in the results, you must think of a rule to decide which row of the multiple rows with the same AccountID is used to get the values AccountTitle and TransactionDate.

Comment: Question is asking for a running total not a single total.

Answer (score 0):

What version of SQL-Server are you using? This should do the trick:

```
       Select AccountID, AccountTitle, TransactionData, 
       SUM(Amount) OVER (partiton by AccountID order by TransactionDate) .
  from yourtable group by AccountID, AccountTitle, TransactionData
```

You take group of rows with AccountID, order them by Transaction date and count SUM in that group by Transaction date .