# Why my record returns same sum for all records?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am passing `accountID` and on the basis of that SP picks amount details of a person e.g.

```
AccountID   AccountTitle  TransactionDate Amount RunningAmount
1           John01        2014/11/28      20        20
```

now if there is 2nd or more records for same `accountID` then it should add with previous e.g. if 2nd record for accountID 1 is 40 then `RunningAmount` should display 60 but amount should display original i.e. 40

```
AccountID   AccountTitle  TransactionDate Amount RunningAmount
    1           John01        2014/12/30    40      60
```

and same goes for further records.

```
Select 
    a.AccountID, a.AccountTitle, t.DateTime as TranasactionDateTime, 
    t.Amount,
    sum(t.Amount) over (partition by t.Account_Id order by t.DateTime) as RunningAmount    
from 
    Payments.Accounts a Inner 
Join
    Payments.Transactions t on a.AccountID = t.Account_ID
where 
    t.Account_ID = 1;
```

It returns this result:

```
AccountID   AccountTitle    TranasactionDateTime    Amount  RunningAmount
1           Test Account    2014-11-28 09:22:00     500.00    1300.00
1           Test Account    2014-11-28 01:12:00     800.00    1300.00
```

but I want it like this

```
AccountID   AccountTitle    TranasactionDateTime    Amount  RunningAmount
1           Test Account    2014-11-28 09:22:00     500.00    500.00
1           Test Account    2014-12-21 01:12:00     800.00    1300.00
1           Test Account    2014-10-11 21:11:01     100.00    1400.00
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?  The `order by` statement in the windowing clause should be doing what you want.  And, your sample data doesn't match your desired results.  The number of rows is different as well as the transaction date/time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add 1 records data to previous?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27189234/how-to-add-1-records-data-to-previous)

Comment: @GordonLinoff so any way to solve ?

Comment: @Blam yes but i tried that and got this ? but now this problem

Comment: Did you understood what he is trying to say. Ask your question clearly your sample data doesn't match with Expected Output

Comment: The problem has not changed.  Rather than paste a solution that does not do what you expect into a new question use comment on the answer to the original question.

Comment: @NoDisplayName check now

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be doing what you want.  You can be even more emphatic with:

```
   sum(t.Amount) over (partition by t.Account_Id
                       order by t.DateTime
                       rows between unbounded preceding and current row
                      ) as RunningAmount
```

Comment: hi i used it but throw error Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near 'row'.

Comment: Select a.AccountID, a.AccountTitle, t.DateTime as TranasactionDateTime, 
       t.Amount,
       sum(t.Amount) over (partition by t.Account_Id
                       order by t.DateTime
                       row between unbounded preceding and current row
                      ) as RunningAmount     
from Payments.Accounts a Inner Join
     Payments.Transactions t
     on a.AccountID = t.Account_ID
where t.Account_ID = 1

Comment: Syntax should be "rows between" (plural rows). Note that the windowing clauses were not available until SQL-Server 2012.